# Olympiad Math Question - Line bisecting an angle in a 2x1 rectangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, contest-math, angle, bisection

Going through some Olympiad Math papers, I came across this question:

> Given a rectangle $ABCD$ as shown in the figure below where $\overline{AB}=2$, $\overline{AD}=1$ and $M$ is on $\overline{CD}$. If $\overline{MA}$ bisects $\angle{DMB}$, find $\overline{DM}$.
> [image]

This probably has something to do with trigonometry, but I'm suspecting that there's an easier way around this.

I set $x=\overline{DM}$ and tried:

$$2\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=180-\arctan\left(\frac{1}{2-x}\right)$$

Because on the left side of the equation, it's the angle $\angle{DMA}$, and on the right side it's $\angle{DMB}$. This does not seem like it would be easy to solve, would there be an easier way around this?

Comment: Take tan of both sides?

Comment: @markvs Any easy way of doing that?

Comment: It is easy: use the formula for $\tan(2x)$ and the formula for $\tan(180-x)$.

Comment: @markvs Thanks for your help! However, this was an Olympiad question, which meant it had to be done quickly and efficiently. The accepted answer does just that.

Comment: I know what Olympiad questions are. I do not know what "efficiently" means re these questions. Nevertheless, you may want to learn some trig.

Comment: @markvs I just mean that I probably want to find a solution that I can use in 1-2 minutes or less. But yeah, I gotta learn some trig ;)

Comment: The formula in your Q leads to a solution in $30$ seconds.

Comment: @markvs The accepted answer probably takes less time than that, and requires less memorizing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\angle DMA=\angle BMA=\alpha.$
Observe,
$$\angle  BAM=90^{\circ}-\angle DAM=\angle DMA=\alpha.$$
$$\implies BM=BA=2.$$
Using the Pythagorean Theorem, $CM=\sqrt{3}\implies DM=2-\sqrt{3}.$

Comment: Nice! Never thought of that. I just forgot that contest maths usually use symmetric properties and other geometric tricks that don't require trigonometry. Thanks!